# Why is Django reverse() failing with unicode?

Tags: python, django, unicode

Here is a django models file that is not working as I would expect.
I would expect the to_url method to do the reverse lookup in the urls.py file, and get a url that would correspond to calling that view with arguments supplied by the Arguments model.

```
from django.db import models
class Element(models.Model):
    viewname = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    arguments = models.ManyToManyField('Argument', null = True, blank = True )

    @models.permalink
    def to_url(self):
        d = dict( self.arguments.values_list('key', 'value') )
        return (self.viewname, (), d)
class Argument(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

The value d ends up as a dictionary from a unicode string to another unicode string, which I believe, should work fine with the reverse() method that would be called by the permalink decorator, however, it results in:

```
TypeError: reverse() keywords must be strings
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `to_url` method, you need to make sure the keys in the `d` dict are *not* Unicode strings.  This isn't peculiar to Django, it's just how keyword arguments to functions work in Python.  Here's a simple example:

```
>>> def f(**kwargs): print kwargs
... 
>>> d1 = { u'foo': u'bar' }
>>> d2 = { 'foo': u'bar' }
>>> f(**d1)
TypeError: f() keywords must be strings
>>> f(**d2)
{'foo': u'bar'}
```

Changing your

```
d = dict( self.arguments.values_list('key', 'value') )
```

into something like

```
d = dict((str(k), v) for k, v in self.arguments.values_list('key', 'value').iteritems())
```

should do the trick.